# Find by String in Spring - REST API

Tags: java, spring, api, rest, jpa

I'm new in Spring boot and Spring data JPA, and I'm trying to make a get request to search the url for all cities with the same UF but I'm not getting it. Can anyone shed some light on how I can do a get to search for the UFs?
I'm trying to do the following:

```
@GetMapping(value = {"/{uf}"})
 public List<Cidade> findByUF(@PathVariable String uf){
      return repositorioCidade.findAll();        
 }
```

Here is how I'm trying to do:

My Repository:

```
public interface RepositorioCidade extends JpaRepository<Cidade,Long>{
    List<Cidade> findByUF(String uf);
}
```

Entity Cidade:

```
@Entity
public class Cidade {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long idCidade;  
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String cidade;      
    private String uf;  
    
    public Long getIdCidade() {
        return idCidade;
    }
    public void setIdCidade(Long idCidade) {
        this.idCidade = idCidade;
    }    
    public String getCidade() {
        return cidade;
    }
    public void setCidade(String cidade) {
        this.cidade = cidade;
    }
    public String getUf() {
        return uf;
    }
    public void setUf(String uf) {
        this.uf = uf;
    }
    

    
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/cidade")
public class CidadeREST {
    @Autowired
    private RepositorioCidade repositorioCidade;

    @GetMapping
    public Page<Cidade> listar(Pageable page){
        return repositorioCidade.findAll(page);
    }           

    // @GetMapping(value = {"/{uf}"})
    // public List<Cidade> findByUF(@PathVariable String uf){
    //     return repositorioCidade.findAll();        
    // }

    @PostMapping
    public void salvar(@RequestBody Cidade cidade){
        repositorioCidade.save(cidade);
    }

    @PutMapping
    public void alterar(@RequestBody Cidade cidade){
        if(cidade.getIdCidade() > 0)
        repositorioCidade.save(cidade);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{idCidade}")
    public void excluir(@PathVariable Long idCidade){
        repositorioCidade.deleteById(idCidade);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, did you try to override findAll() in your repository file ?
```java
@Override
List<Cidade> findAll();
```

Comment: @Majestic didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to link `findByUF()` method instead of JPA inbuild method `findAll()` with repository object in controller.

**Your repository should become**

```
public interface RepositorioCidade extends JpaRepository<Cidade,Long>{
    @Query(nativeQuery= true, value="SELECT * FROM cidade WHERE uf = ?")
    List<Cidade> findByUF(String uf);
}
```

*OR*

```
public interface RepositorioCidade extends JpaRepository<Cidade,Long>{
    List<Cidade> findByUF(String uf);
}
```

**Your Controller should become**

```
@GetMapping(value = {"/{uf}"})
public List<Cidade> findByUF(@PathVariable String uf){
    return repositorioCidade.findByUF(uf);        
}
```

Comment: There is no need to make a native query, a simple override works.

Comment: It's because OP uses *findAll()* that I'm not telling him to create a new method with a native query. And why is it totally wrong to use *findAll()* to get data from DB ?

Comment: @FaeemazazBhanej I'm trying this but I when execute GET method in postman and try the url "http://localhost:8080/cidade/MG" to GET all city with uf=MG I get 500 Internal Server Error and in the console says "Ambiguous handler methods mapped for '/cidade/MG': {public void com.example.restapi.CidadeREST.excluir(java.lang.Long), public java.util.List com.example.restapi.CidadeREST.findByUF(java.lang.String)}] with root cause"

Comment: @Dr.VonGravly You got ambiguous url error because you have same url for delete operation and findbyUf operation is same change one of them

Comment: @FaeemazazBhanej Ok man, now I get it, thank you so much.

Comment: @Dr.VonGravly You most welcome glad to help

Answer (score 1):

I saw in your code that you called a method in the controller that does not exist in the repository layer
change body of findByUF

```
@GetMapping(value = {"/{uf}"})
public List<Cidade> findByUF(@PathVariable String uf){
  return repositorioCidade.findAll();        
}
```

to this:

```
@GetMapping(value = {"/{uf}"})
public List<Cidade> findByUF(@PathVariable String uf){
  return repositorioCidade.findByUF(uf);        
}
```